# Don't know where to put the code in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

Total newbie with Leaflet. I'm looking at the tutorial at

https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/

Where do I need to enter the code?

Do I put it in the .js file or do I need another .json file?

Comment: If you click through the 'View the full example' link at the bottom of that page you get to https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html - look at the source of that page for a minimal implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck even at that point...

https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Where do I put 

var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

Comment: OK I think I understand... I put the var directly in the script section...  I use a wordpress plugin; do you think it can be done that way? Where should I put the script info into the wordpress plugin? I use Leaflet map plugin.

Comment: Sounds like you'd better add a WordPress tag to your question.

Comment: I'm testing without wordpress and got some results... but I'm stuck when trying to convert .shp/.gml/.map files from Statistic Canada to JSON...  Anyone know how to convert those? I tried mapshaper but didn't get any coordonates data...

Comment: Please either edit your question or ask a new question.